# Using curl for Aria project in command window I get what I want but in PHP file it return empty string

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

when I type this command in git bash:

```
curl -i -X POST --header "content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" --header "Authorization: Bearer X" -d @RequestBody.json https://app.studio.arria.com:443/alite_content_generation_webapp/text/X
```

I get:

> HTTP/2 200 date: Thu, 22 Nov 2018 09:45:27 GMT content-type:
>   application/json;charset=UTF-8 server: nginx
>
> [{"errorType":null,"errorMessage":null,"warnings":[],"result":"
>
> Victoria
>   has a land mass of 227,416 square kilometers and a population in 2016
>   of 5,938,100, which is 7.04% up on 2010's figure of 5,547,500.
>    The capital city, Melbourne, has a population of 4,353,514,
>   which is 10.11% up on 2010's count of 3,953,939, and represents 73.31%
>   of the state's population.
>
> The premier, Daniel Andrews (ALP), is
>   in his first
>   term.
>
> ","wordCount":60},{"errorType":null,"errorMessage":null,"warnings":[],"result":"
>
> The
>   Australian Capital Territory has a land mass of 2,358 square
>   kilometers and a population in 2016 of 390,800, which is 8.89% up on
>   2010's figure of 358,900.  The capital city, Canberra, has a
>   population of 424,666, which is 6.58% up on 2010's count of 398,430,
>   and represents 73.31% of the state's population.
>
> The premier,
>   Andrew Barr (ALP), is in his first
>   term.
>
> ","wordCount":63},{"errorType":null,"errorMessage":null,"warnings":[],"result":"
>
> The
>   Northern Territory has a land mass of 1,349,129 square kilometers and
>   a population in 2016 of 244,600, which is 6.49% up on 2010's figure of
>   229,700.  The capital city, Darwin, has a population of 123,396,
>   which is 9.21% up on 2010's count of 112,987, and represents 73.31% of
>   the state's population.
>
> The premier, Michael Gunner (ALP), is in
>   his first term.
>
> ","wordCount":62}]

but when I use PHP file, in which I paste commands that I get from [Curl to PHP](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/)

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.studio.arria.com:443/alite_content_generation_webapp/text/X");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$post = array(
    "file" => "@" .realpath("RequestBody.json")
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer X";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}else {
    var_dump($result);
    $json = json_decode($result,true);
    var_dump($json);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

`var_dump($result)` returns

> string(0) ""

and `var_dump($json)` returns

> NULL

I changed Authorization Bearer and ID of the project in the url to X for this post, but if you think the problem might be in those things I can post the original commands.

RequestBody.json:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "Primary",
        "type": "1d",
        "dataSet": [
          ["State", "Premier", "Party", "Terms", "StateLandArea", "StatePop2010", "StatePop2016", "Capital", "CapitalPop2010", "CapitalPop2016"],
          ["Victoria", "Daniel Andrews", "ALP", "1", "227,416", "5,547,500", "5,938,100", "Melbourne", "3,953,939", "4,353,514"],
          ["the Australian Capital Territory", "Andrew Barr", "ALP", "1", "2,358", "358,900", "390,800", "Canberra", "398,430", "424,666"],
          ["the Northern Territory", "Michael Gunner", "ALP", "1", "1,349,129", "229,700", "244,600", "Darwin", "112,987", "123,396"]
        ]
      }
    ],
    "options": {
      "nullValueBehaviour": "SHOW_IDENTIFIER",
      "contentOutputFormat": "HTML"
    }
  }
```

Comment: In the command line version, you're setting the content type to `application/json` but in your PHP code, you're setting it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Yes, change you use JSON in your request so change line. `$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json"`.

Comment: You should also read the contents of your json file and add it as body. Currently, you seem to be sending it as a file

Comment: That helped, now I read the json file, put the content in the variable $data and then `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);` and also changed `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json` in `$headers[] = "Content-Type: ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use the @ method with php's libcurl wrapper, it was deprecated in PHP 5.5, disabled-by-default in PHP 5.6, and completely removed in PHP 7.0. if you're using PHP 5.5 or newer, use CURLFile instead,

```
$post = array(
    "file" => new CURLFile("RequestBody.json")
);
```

but that's not why your php code isn't working, when you give CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS an array in php, curl will create your post request in the `multipart/form-data` format, whilst your curl cli invocation will send the data json-encoded. to have php-curl send the json in the post body just like your cli invocation does, give the raw json string to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS directly, or if you have the response in a file already, use CURLOPT_INFILE,

this should be the equivalent request in PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init ();
$fp = fopen ( "RequestBody.json", "rb" );
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_INFILE => $fp,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                "content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                "Authorization: Bearer X" 
        ),
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://app.studio.arria.com:443/alite_content_generation_webapp/text/X' 
) );
curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );
fclose ( $fp );
```

or alternatively if your request body is dynamic/mutable, you can do:

```
$post=array (
        'data' => array (

                array (
                        'id' => 'Primary',
                        'type' => '1d',
                        'dataSet' => array (

                                array (
                                        'State',
                                        'Premier',
                                        'Party',
                                        'Terms',
                                        'StateLandArea',
                                        'StatePop2010',
                                        'StatePop2016',
                                        'Capital',
                                        'CapitalPop2010',
                                        'CapitalPop2016' 
                                ),

                                array (
                                        'Victoria',
                                        'Daniel Andrews',
                                        'ALP',
                                        '1',
                                        '227,416',
                                        '5,547,500',
                                        '5,938,100',
                                        'Melbourne',
                                        '3,953,939',
                                        '4,353,514' 
                                ),

                                array (
                                        'the Australian Capital Territory',
                                        'Andrew Barr',
                                        'ALP',
                                        '1',
                                        '2,358',
                                        '358,900',
                                        '390,800',
                                        'Canberra',
                                        '398,430',
                                        '424,666' 
                                ),

                                array (
                                        'the Northern Territory',
                                        'Michael Gunner',
                                        'ALP',
                                        '1',
                                        '1,349,129',
                                        '229,700',
                                        '244,600',
                                        'Darwin',
                                        '112,987',
                                        '123,396' 
                                ) 
                        ) 
                ) 
        ),
        'options' => array (
                'nullValueBehaviour' => 'SHOW_IDENTIFIER',
                'contentOutputFormat' => 'HTML' 
        ) 
);
```

and then:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($post,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

instead of using CURLOPT_INFILE.